# PHP - Two buttons to insert record then go to different pages

Tags: php, forms

I would like to have 2 buttons on my form. One to insert record then go to page 1, and another to insert record and go to page 2. My PHP knowledge isn't too good so I'm probably making a simple mistake. Here's my code - thanks in advance!

```
<?php 
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO content (title) VALUES (%s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_sql, $sql);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $sql) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "page1.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}




$editFormAction2 = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction2 .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO content (title) VALUES (%s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_sql, $sql);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $sql) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "page2.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form name="form" method="POST" id="form">
<input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Page Title"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Next Step" onClick="this.form.action='<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>';     this.form.submit()">
<input type="submit" class="save" value="Save & Exit" onClick="this.form.action='<?php echo $editFormAction2    ; ?>';     this.form.submit()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*()` extension, instead use PDO or MySQLi. Why? [note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) the red box, its been there for about 4.5 years now.

Comment: what @Xorifelse said, and also your $editFromAction and $editFormAction2 are both "pointing" to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] so you are submitting the form to the same php file. what you could do is add another hidden input field to your form and onClick manipulate the value of that field and then do the redirect based on that input field. (don't forget to validate all user input, always :))

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div style="float: left;">
<form action="page1.php" name="form" method="POST" id="form">
    <input name="title" id="title" type="text" placeholder="Page Title"/>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Next Step">

</form>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<form action="page2.php" name="form" method="POST" id="form">
    <input name="title2" id="title2" type="hidden" placeholder="Page Title"/>
    <input type="submit" class="save" value="Save & Exit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#title2").val($("#title").val());
    });
    $(document).change(function() {
        $("#title2").val($("#title").val());
    });
</script>
```